# In Vim, how to choose the nth suggested file while doing :edit?

Tags: vim, autocomplete

This is a total newbie vim question. Apologies for the basic-ness involved.

I need to open a lot of files. The `:edit <file-name>` command seems to open a file and I also see a filename auto-complete feature, which searches for all similar file names in the path. But I don't know how to choose one of those suggestions quickly without writing the whole file name.

Answer (score 2):

```
set wildmenu
```

enables the "wildmenu" where you navigate with `<Tab>` and `<S-Tab>`, enter a subdirectory with `<Down>` and select a file with `<CR>`.

See `:help 'wildmenu'` and `:help 'wildmode'`.

Note that `:edit` can only open one file. If you want to open multiple files at once, use `:args models/*.php`.

Another, more familiar, way to open files is to use the built-in netrw:

```
:Explore
```

See `:help netrw` for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might enjoy the conveniences of the rather smashing CTRL-P plugin. https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim

It will allow you to type any substring of the filename to narrow the available files down. You can mark multiple files for opening.